# How to do grouping and aggregations when data bind by ajax in Telerik Grid

Tags: c#, ajax, telerik, telerik-grid

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Orders")
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
          //Ajax binding
          .Ajax()
               //The action method which will return JSON
               .Select("_AjaxBinding", "Home")
    )
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
%>
```

My Telerik has an implementation like this and it uses ajax data binding 
How to use aggregation and grouping ?

Comment: It looks like you are using an older version of the Telerik MVC extensions.  What version do you have installed?  Do you have access to the latest KendoUI MVC extensions?  Those are the recommended Telerik-MVC UI tool.  If not, we can troubleshoot through this version as well

Comment: well we were permitted to use the legacy telerik components for ASP.net yes we will migrate to kendo soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the KendoUI (and latest) version of the grid, there is a demo of how to do the Aggregate functionality at:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/aggregates

Make sure your _AjaxBinding action method in your HomeController handles the KendoUI DataSourceRequest and returns JSON formatted to be a DataSourceResult.  That source code should look something like this:

```
public ActionResult _AjaxBinding([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
  return Json(MyModelToReturn.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeff Thank you we will look on to this :)